# Why is my variable jumping in value when I add an "if" condition?

Tags: c++, arduino

The code below, without the if statement, count's up from 1 to infinite and shows this in the console as intended.
If I add the if statement, I get what's shown in the screenshot below. Why does this happen?

```
#include <Arduino_MKRIoTCarrier.h>
MKRIoTCarrier carrier;
int a;
int r,g,b;


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
    delay(1500); 
    carrier.begin();
    carrier.display.setRotation(0);
    a = 1;
}

void loop() 
{
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    Serial.println(a);
    a = a + 1;

    if (a = 10)
    {
        carrier.leds.setPixelColor(0, 255, 0, 0);
        carrier.leds.show();
    }
}
```

[image: strange counting]

Comment: It's because you used `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: `if (a = 10)` should be `if (a == 10)`.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++, comparison is `==`, so you need to write `if (a == 10)`. When you write, `a = 10`, that's an assignment: `a` will have the value of `10` and the evaluation value is also `10` (to be precise, reference to `a` which is `10`), thus in `if()` it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Prefer to comment and close as typo.

Comment: ohhhhh my god, thank you! Coming from c++ I did not realize this even could be the issue!

Comment: This is the same in `c++` and `c`